# How do I take in image view in iOS and make it go behind the other layers to make it the background?

Tags: ios, uiimageview

There isn't really code for this it's more on the story board.

I have tried to go to the attributes and size modifier but I can't find anything that makes the UIImageView the background.

Comment: Instead of making it an image view, maybe you could make it the background of a UIView. I'm normally talking some code here, but it need be minimal - add a UIView in the IB view hierarchy appropriately and in code merely make it the background.

Answer (score 1):

Just Drag the uiimageview in the left side, and drop it to the top of the other component.

Comment: By the left side, I'm assuming you mean the outline view.

Comment: Yes the left bar when you open the xib

Answer (score 0):

Just set an image as the backgroundColor, something like:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: image)
```

See: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicolor for more details.